# Makeblock Arduino keeps stopping from motor overpower protection

Tags: motor

I got a makeblock Arduino. Sometimes when I make it go forward at full speed, all motors stop for 3 seconds and it beeps shortly. I think it is that the motors are a little hard to turn for a moment and it stops to prevent damage to the motors. It is getting very annoying. Is there any way to disable it or make it less sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely the pause in operation is because of the motors.  It is more likely the [Makeblock](http://wiki.makeblock.cc/index.php?title=Getting_Started_with_Makeblock) is stopping because the  motor controllers are too hot.  Next time try to identify which chips on the board are controlling the motors and test if they are getting hot to the touch.  If so, consider adding heat sinks to these chips to mitigate any heat dissipation problems.

An alternative explanation involves a limited power supply.  It could be that when the motors are demanding high current, the voltage drops and the processor resets.  Consider a power supply that can offer more amperage.  Or larger capacity batteries.